# Json problem in fetching data

Tags: javascript, json

```
<script>
  function jsonfunc(){
   var data ="publick="+document.getElementById("publickeyval").value+"&privatek="+document.getElementById("privatekeyval").value;

   var url="http://www.remoteapiserver.com/example_api/example_adcpatchaapi.php?"+data;
   alert(url);
  var my_JSON_object = {}; 
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_request.open( "GET", url, true );
http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (http_request.readyState == 4){
      alert(http_request.responseText+"#"); // showing only # //
       my_JSON_object = JSON.parse( http_request.responseText );
  }
};
http_request.send(null);


  }
  </script>
```

I was as asked my question as per comment i read Json and writing above code in my php page.But still this is giving problem.I am not getting fetched dada from remote server.I am getting only "#" in alert box.

Comment: Do a search on stack overflow, this has been awnsered many times. XMLHTTPRequest does not work cross domain!

Comment: .. at least not by default, but there's a way to make it work cross domain. but it only works on ie8 (correct me if i'm wrong) and FF3.4

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend a JavaScript Framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for this kind of stuff. It definitely makes this a lot easier. jQuery lets you do cross-domain requests, if you use JSONP (take a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)). The code would look something like this:

```
$.getJSON(yourUrlGoesHere, function(data) { // ready callback
    // data is an object; no need to parse it manually.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it't better use some library:
JQuery or Moootools: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.JSON

Implement this in native JS is difficulty if we want use it in all browsers ;)